# Use cases of ":rewind"? How does it differ from ":b1"?

Tags: buffers, ex-command, argument-list

After reading `:help :rewind`

```
:rew[ind] [++opt] [+cmd]  
    Start editing the first file in the argument list.
    This fails when changes have been made and Vim does
    not want to |abandon| the current buffer.
    Also see |++opt| and |+cmd|. {Vi: no ++opt}
```

and `:help :buffer`

```
:[N]b[uffer][!] [+cmd] [N]      *:b* *:bu* *:buf* *:buffer* *E86*
    Edit buffer [N] from the buffer list.  If [N] is not given,
    the current buffer remains being edited.  See |:buffer-!| for
    [!].  This will also edit a buffer that is not in the buffer
    list, without setting the 'buflisted' flag.
    Also see |+cmd|.
```

comes the question: What does `:rewind` offer that `:b1` lacks?

Comment: This is completely different things. Start from reading `:h arglist`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was told in the comments, the fundamental difference is that
`:b1` targets the buffer list and `:rewind` targets the argument list.
`:help buffer-list` is a nice summary:

```
    args list          buffer list         meaning
:[N]argument [N]    :[N]buffer [N]      to arg/buf N
:[N]next [file ..]  :[N]bnext [N]       to Nth next arg/buf
:[N]Next [N]        :[N]bNext [N]       to Nth previous arg/buf
:[N]previous [N]    :[N]bprevious [N]   to Nth previous arg/buf
:rewind / :first    :brewind / :bfirst  to first arg/buf
:last               :blast              to last arg/buf
:all                :ball               edit all args/buffers
                    :unhide             edit all loaded buffers
                    :[N]bmod [N]        to Nth modified buf
```

The **argument list** are the arguments passed `Vim` on startup. It hardly ever changes (`:argedit`, `:argadd`, etc. can change them though).

```
vim file1 file2
```

means the argument list contains file1 and file2.

The **buffer list** is not static. With `:e file3`, it incorporates file3,
so `:ls` shows the three files while `:args` shows only file1 and file2.

Resuming the experiment, wipe the 1st buffer with `:bwipe 1`. Buffer 1 has been wiped and thus removed from the buffer list. Now,

- `:b1`
  raises an error "Buffer 1 does not exist",
- `:brewind` goes to the first
  buffer in the buffer list, file2,
- `:rewind` brings back file1 in a new buffer,
  since the argument list is unchanged and the first argument is file1.

Comment: Another difference is that one targets the buffer list while the other targets the argument list

Comment: @D.BenKnoble After a careful read, I think now I've got it. Please let me know if I made some mistake or if I still miss the point.

Comment: Looks great! Technically it's possible to change the arguments list (e.g., many forms of `:args`, `:argadd`, `:argdelete`), but that's probably a tertiary detail

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you very much! I have edited that too so as to avoid innacuracies.